# Return one element from where-clause or the first one

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to query my database with Entity Framework 5 in the following manner:

`userProfile = context.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(up => up.UserId == userId && up.IsActive);`

Now this clearly throws an exception when more than one user profile is present (due to the `SingleOrDefault`).

How can I construct my query so I get the **active** userprofile from the current user (`up.UserId == userId`) **or** the first one when no userprofile is active?

I totally know how to do this in two queries, but I think that would be too much overhead and this should be possible with just one query:

```
userProfile = context.UserProfiles.Single(up => up.UserId == userId && up.IsActive); // throws exception when not exactly one

if (userProfile == null)
{
    userProfile = context.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(up => up.UserId == userId);
}
```

**Edit:**

I'm now using this as my parameter and works flawlessly with the `IsActive` property:
`context.UserProfiles.Where(up => up.UserId == userId).OrderByDescending(up => up.IsActive).FirstOrDefault();`

Now when there is no `IsActive == true` row, I'd like to order them by their `LastUsed` date and select the one that's lately being used:

`context.UserProfiles.Where(up => up.UserId == userId).OrderByDescending(up => up.IsActive).OrderByDescending(up => up.LastUsed).FirstOrDefault();`

Sadly this **always** returns the latest one, even when there's a row containing `IsActive == true`

Comment: order by IsActive descending, and take the first?

Comment: Oh, you're right - of course. This has worked. Thank you :)

Comment: You need to use `ThenByDescending` instead of the second `OrderByDescending`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
var userProfile = context.UserProfiles.Where(up => up.UserId == userId)
                       .OrderByDescending(up => up.IsActive).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you, I can accept an answer in two minutes. Would you please also review my edit and give out your thoughts on this? :)

Comment: @SeToY the second of those should be `ThenByDescending`; otherwise a recent inactive one will take precedence over a less recent but active one.

Answer (score 1):

Your second `OrderByDescending` ignores any ordering done by the previous one. You need to use `ThenByDescending` instead:

```
context.UserProfiles
    .Where(up => up.UserId == userId)
    .OrderByDescending(up => up.IsActive)
    .ThenByDescending(up => up.LastUsed)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```